# XServer first key typed is always in lowercase

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, x11, xserver

I'm writing a method for keyboard handling where I'm passing the key unicodes and firing keystrokes using the XTestFakeKeyEvent Method of X11. Now my issue is that after the opening the display, if the very first Character I send is in Uppercase, it still is typed in lowercase. So provided is the minimal implementation.
Compiled using command: **gcc typekeys.c -o typekeys.exe -lX11 -lXtst**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
static Display *mainDisplay = NULL;


Display *XGetMainDisplayK(void) {
    if (mainDisplay == NULL) {
        mainDisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        if (mainDisplay == NULL) {
            printf("\nCould not open main display");
        }
    }
    return mainDisplay;

}

void toggleKeySym(unsigned int key){
    KeySym sym;
    Display *dpy;
    dpy = XGetMainDisplayK();
    sym=key;
    printf("\nKeysym recieved:%u \n",key);
    int min, max, numcodes;
    XDisplayKeycodes(dpy, &min, &max);
    KeySym *keysym;
    keysym = XGetKeyboardMapping(dpy, min, max-min+1, &numcodes);
    keysym[(max-min-1)*numcodes]=sym;
    XChangeKeyboardMapping(dpy, min, numcodes, keysym, (max-min));
    XFree(keysym);
    XFlush(dpy);
    unsigned int code;
    printf("Keysym value:%d \n",sym);
    code=XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, sym);
    printf("Code Generated:%u. \n",code);
    XTestFakeKeyEvent(dpy, code, True, CurrentTime);
    XTestFakeKeyEvent(dpy, code, False, CurrentTime);
    XSync(dpy, false);
    XFlush(dpy);
}

void main(){
    printf("Start \n");
    toggleKeySym(65);
    toggleKeySym(65);
    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, sym);`:

If you look at the output of your program, you will see that it outputs something like this:

```
Code Generated:38.
...
Code Generated:254.
```

At least on my computer it behaves this way.

(By the way: I can only reproduce the problem the first time after logging off from my computer and logging on again.)

However, your program should write the same value twice because the same key code (254) is pressed.

This means that `XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, sym);` has returned the wrong value.

The reason is that `XKeysymToKeycode()` works the following way:

The `XOpenDisplay()` function calls `XGetKeyboardMapping()` reading the keyboard information to some "internal" variable (of the type `KeySym *`); the information in the "internal" variable is then used by `XKeysymToKeycode()`.

The "internal" variable is updated later - maybe during `XSync()`. However, it seems that the "internal" variable is not updated before `XKeysymToKeycode()` is called the first time, so `XKeysymToKeycode()` returns the information still based on the old value of the "internal" variable.

However, you know that you have changed the symbol generated by the key `max-1`, so you know that `code` should have the value `max-1`. Therefore, calling `XKeysymToKeycode()` is not necessary at all.